# How can I use CiviCRM's cache table?

Tags: extension, developer, cache

When developing an extension, I'd like to cache some data to avoid the expense of re-calculating it. Is there a civicrm version of the Drupal's caching interface for developers?

Answer (score 4):

I found the corresponding reference page here:

https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/cache/

Looks straightforward:

1. Set a cache value with Civi::cache()->set('mykey', 'myvalue');
2. Get a cached value with Civi::cache()->get('mykey');
3. Delete a cached value with Civi::cache()->delete('mykey');
4. Flush the entire cache with Civi::cache()->flush();

As far as I know, the civicrm caching schema is pretty simple, there's just one key/value table.

As an aside - I just discovered that Herb @ freeform has contributed a recent patch for using Redis as the cache backend. I'm a Redis fan also, so thanks Herb!

Comment: So Civi::cache is an in-memory cache? It's a bit confusing since I saw the `civicrm_cache` table and would expect the cache to use that. I was hoping to use this to persist data between requests instead of implementing it myself.

Comment: No, the caching mechanism is abstracted and persistent - it might be using Redis for performance, but the canonical implementation is indeed that civicrm_cache table. But it's not designed for user session data, it's for configuration type data.