# How to let extension users choose cache system?

Tags: extension, php, cache

CiviCRM contains some useful caching infrastructure ([confluence wiki](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Cache+Reference) and [related question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7340/how-can-i-use-civicrms-cache-table)).

If I am creating a module and I would like to allow users to override the default `Civi::cache()` **specifically for this extension** how should I do that?

I think putting some settings (maybe a factory function?) in the `civicrm.settings.php` would be the best way? Is this correct? And any examples?

I'm thinking I could just put something like this in my code:

`if (function_exists('myextension_cach_factory')) {
  $cache = myextension_cach_factory();
}
else {
  $cache = Civi::cache();
}`

Then the settings file could contain something like

`// civicrm.settings.php
function myextension_cache_factory() {
  return new CRM_Utils_Cache_SerializeCache(array());
}`

or maybe even:

`//civicrm.settings.php
function myextension_cache_factory() {
  return new CRM_Utils_Cache_Memcached(array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 11211,
    'timeout' => 3600,
    'prefix' => 'mec_',
  ));
}`

### Background:

`$civicrm_root/CRM/Utils/Cache/Interface.php` defines a minimal standard interface for caching with get(), set(), delete() and flush() methods.

`$civicrm_root/CRM/Utils/Cache/` has these useful looking implementations:

`APCcache.php
ArrayCache.php
Memcache.php
Memcached.php
NoCache.php
SerializeCache.php 
SqlGroup.php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. CRM_Utils_Cache::create()

When looking through the list of cache drivers, you see options like `Memcache`, `Memcached`, and `Redis`. Generally there's little reason why a deployment would use all three -- rather, the typical question this:

- Do we have *any* kind of high-speed/shared/memory-based cache? If so, use it.
- Do we have any kind of SQL-backed cache? If so, use it.
- Otherwise, use an ephemeral `array()` (for the duration each request)

In v4.7, `CRM_Utils_Cache::create()` is a factory function which accepts an ordered list of drivers, and it picks the first one that's usable, e.g.

```
$myCache = CRM_Utils_Cache::create(array(
  'name' => 'somethingsomething',
  'type' => array('*memory*', 'SqlGroup', 'ArrayCache'),
));
```

This aims to address the typical use-case by making it unnecessary for the admin to configure anything extra for your specific extension.

Your extension would need to retain a copy of that cache object, e.g.

```
function myextension_cache() {
  if (!isset(Civi::$statics['myextension_cache'])) {
    Civi::$statics['myextension_cache'] = CRM_Utils_Cache::create(array(
      'name' => 'somethingsomething',
      'type' => array('*memory*', 'SqlGroup', 'ArrayCache'),
    ));
  }
  return Civi::$statics['myextension_cache'];
}
```

I believe this answers the typical requirement/issue when someone wants to configure the extension's cache, but it doesn't literally answer the question...

#### 2. Named services and caching

The [Symfony service container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html) is a general-purpose tool for naming and tracking a bunch of objects -- cache services, database services, entity-repositories, etc. Rather than have a hundred functions like `myextension_cache()` which hard-code the factory, we put all the factories together in the container. This pattern improves our leverage; in principle, you can expose the container to different processes, e.g.

- Reading multiple YAML/XML files to configure the container
- Allowing extensions/hooks to alter the container
- Allowing site admins to alter the container
- Allowing dev-tools and admin-tools to inspect the container

For this reason, new caches in core tend to be [created through the container](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.7.14/Civi/Core/Container.php#L159), e.g.

- [`Civi::cache()`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.7.14/Civi.php#L28) is equivalent to `Civi::container()->get('cache.default')`
- [`Civi::cache('js_strings')`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.7.14/Civi.php#L28) is equivalent to `Civi::container()->get('cache.js_strings')`

However, at this point, the container in Civi needs improvement. For example, you can alter the container via [`hook_civicrm_container`](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_container), but there's no YAML/XML/annotation mechanism for updating the container, and there's no mechanism for site-admins to modify services via config file (`civicrm.settings.php`).

The long-term goal is to shift more service-management into a container so that questions like "How does a site admin customize service X?" have a categorical answer. Improving the container is very much patch-welcome.